# Collaborate on UML online

Tags: uml, collaboration

Some friends and I are starting up a hobby programming project.
I wonder if there is any good method/tool/service which lets us collaborate on UML diagrams online.
This can be in any form (online direct edit, source-control style, etc.) as long as we can make changes independent of each other.

Comment: Why don't you just use a source control system?

Comment: You could read [this](http://savedelete.com/collaborative-online-diagramming-tools.html) and try them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is to share my model and my diagrams directly on CVS inside my project. 
After each major change I commit.

Anyone in the team can change the model or the diagrams. It works pretty well because the class diagram is synchronized with the code and no offline out of box code generation is used.

Comment: This is the method we ended up using. We are programming in C# using Visual Studio so we just added a Modelling project to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to create a CASE tool that allows different users to change things simultaneously.

In the past, Texas Instruments created IEF that is a repository based tool based on batch check-out and check-in process. A similar product ERWin also uses a repository for storing the model meta data. None used the collaborative style. The challenge is to handle conflicting user interactions, for example one user may be defining a proper in a class while the other user attempts to delete or rename the class either in the same diagram or in another one.

Also, it is generally good idea to have one person in charge of a diagram. Ideas are welcome but final implementation should be a single person's responsibility unless the model is well divided into separate parts.